# I Can See Source Code on Browser Even After I Uglify the Project

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5, uglifyjs, craco, terser-webpack-plugin

My problem is, I can see my source code in browser even after I use Terser Plugin with Webpack. The problem is, I use Terser Plugin for transforming my code into non human readable code chunks. After browsing my files, I am pretty sure chunks and all the gibberish is not human readable. But somehow when I serve the project, I can see my code unminified and/or unuglified with folder structure intact. So the minified and/or uglified version probably improve my load time but if I am able to see source code in the browser, how can I protect it from other clients?

I am guessing, with sourcemaps you can beautify the project. But I can not find a solution if I can manipulate sourcemap or dont use at all. But its just a guess.

Now some technical inputs:

I created the project with CRA and use craco for disrupting original webpack configuration.

```
const path = require("path");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (argv) => {
    const webpack = {
        alias: {
            components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
            context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/context"),
            hooks: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/hooks"),
            router: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/router"),
            services: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/services"),
            utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utilities"),
            uiKit: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/uiKit"),
        },

        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: "multiple",
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: "all",
            },
        },
        entry: {
            index: {
                import: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.jsx"),
            },
        },
    };
    if (argv.env && argv.env === "production") {
        webpack.optimization = {
            ...webpack.optimization,
            minimize: true,
            nodeEnv: "production",
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        format: {
                            comments: false,
                        },
                        compress: true,
                    },
                    extractComments: false,
                }),
            ],
        };
    }

    return webpack;
};
```

package.json scripts

```
        "start": "npx env-cmd -f config/dev.env craco start",
        "build:test": "npx env-cmd -f config/test.env craco build",
        "build:prod": "npx env-cmd -f config/prod.env craco build",
```

package.json Dev Dependencies

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
        "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.26",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.26",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.26",
        "@storybook/addon-styling": "^1.3.2",
        "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.26",
        "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.0.26",
        "@storybook/react": "^7.0.26",
        "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.26",
        "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
        "clean-jsdoc-theme": "^4.2.9",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.42.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
        "jsdoc": "^4.0.2",
        "jsdoc-to-markdown": "^8.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.25",
        "storybook": "^7.0.26",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
        "webpack": "^5.88.1"
    }
```

package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
        "@arcgis/core": "^4.27.6",
        "@loadable/component": "^5.15.3",
        "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "^1.4.3",
        "@rive-app/react-canvas": "^4.3.3",
        "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "cbs-panorama": "^1.0.65",
        "clsx": "^1.2.1",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "geojson-to-svg": "^1.1.4",
        "hls.js": "^1.4.10",
        "i18next": "^23.3.0",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
        "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.1",
        "maplibre-gl": "3.6.2",
        "proj4": "^2.9.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-color": "^2.19.3",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-i18next": "^13.0.2",
        "react-icomoon": "^2.5.7",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
        "swiper": "^10.2.0",
        "three": "^0.162.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
```

Code in folder

[image]

Code Context

[image]

Code in the Browser

[image]

As you can see code in folder looks uglified but not in the browser. I am guessing it is related to sourcemap but may be something else.

Comment: Don't deploy .map files to production…?! They're useful in testing, but if you want to obfuscate your code in production, those files are counter productive.

Comment: I am asking how to do that specifically. If my code works, I don't need them at all. But how?

Comment: Probably craco can't override cra webpack configuration because nothing worked with build script. I have tried;

  devtool: false,
  productionSourceMap: false,
                mode : "production"

I solve the problem with external js file and call it with build script that removes recursively .map files. I could not share the code because its too long context for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the syntax difference between webpack and craco.
"devtool" and "optimization" keys must be nested within the "configure" key.

you can do it this way:

```
module.exports = {
webpack: {
    mode: 'production',
    alias: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/context"),
        hooks: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/hooks"),
        router: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/router"),
        services: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/services"),
        utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utilities"),
        uiKit: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/uiKit"),
    },
    entry: {
  index: {
    import: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.jsx")
  },
},
    configure: {
        devtool: false, 
        optimization : {
            runtimeChunk: "multiple",
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: "all",
            },
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        format: {
                            comments: false,
                        },
                        compress: true,
                    },
                    extractComments: false,
                }),
            ],
        }
    }
} }
```

happy coding :)